# Android: Sequential Drawing Without Erasing Previously Drawn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

Consider that you want to animate a list of paths sequentially.

I have a custom View that can store a list of path and I override the onDraw method so that I can select the path to animate. I do that with the index called currentPath.

```
var pathList = mutableListOf<Path>()
var currentPath = 0

public override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (!this.pathList.isEmpty()){
            canvas.drawPath(this.pathList[this.currentPath], brushOutput)
        }

    }
```

I am able to animate a path using a property animation.
To do that I have a class OnePath that encapsulate everything to animate one path

```
class OnePath(val brush: Paint, val length: Float, val view: PaintView, val currentPath: Int): Path() {

    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "phase", 1.0f, 0.0f)

    fun setPhase(phase: Float) {
        view.currentPath = currentPath  // set the index of the path to draw in the view
        brush.pathEffect = createPathEffect(length, phase, 1.0f) // animate model output
        view.invalidate() /* will call onDraw */        
    }

    private fun createPathEffect(pathLength: Float, phase: Float, offset: Float): PathEffect {
        return DashPathEffect(
            floatArrayOf(pathLength, pathLength),
            Math.max(phase * pathLength, offset)
        )
    }
}
```

And then to animate the list of path sequentially I use an AnimatorSet with the following

```
val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
val listAnimator = mutableListOf<Animator>()

for (i in 0..len-1){
    val path_i = OnePath(paint, lengthList[i], binding.paintView, i)
    listAnimator.add(path_i.animator)
}
animatorSet.playSequentially(listAnimator)
animatorSet.setDuration(2000).start()
```

However, the result of this, is that each path is animated in order, but whenever a path has been drawn, it disapears when the next path is being animated.

What I want, is to keep each path that has been animated on the screen. How would you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pair of `Bitmap` and `Canvas` to cache the previously drawn paths in `PaintView`:

```
private Canvas extraCanvas;
private Bitmap extraBitmap;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if(extraBitmap != null && !extraBitmap.isRecycled()){
        extraBitmap.recycle();
    }
    extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    extraCanvas = new Canvas(extraBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!this.pathList.isEmpty()){
        extraCanvas.drawPath(pathList.get(currentPath), brushOutput);
    }

    // Draw the bitmap that has all the saved paths:
    canvas.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
}
```

See also the codelab on [Drawing on Canvas Objects](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-canvas/#0)

Comment: Do you think it can also work for animation ? I have already seen this colab, but not tried it yet. in fact I have the same kind of interface to draw on the screen. But animating drawing from touch input, and animating those same lines are two different tasks.

Comment: @jmamath - I used it with your AnimatorSet and got all paths drawn sequentially. None of them was erased.

Comment: Ok, let me try it.